# How customize length of rule in tables?

Tags: tables, booktabs

I want to customize the length of the midrule (xy cm) in the first table. The second table should be default. How can that be done?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
XXXXXXX&\\\midrule\addlinespace[1ex]
\begin{minipage}[t]{5.5cm}
AAAAAAAAAAAAA
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}[t]{9.5cm}
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
YYYYYYYYYYYYY&\\\midrule\addlinespace[1ex]
\begin{minipage}[t]{5.5cm}
CCCCCCCCC
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}[t]{9.5cm}
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** Extension of the original question! While the answers solve the problem above, I do not manage to use them to solve the following: In the second minimal example I want the rule in the second table to have exactly the same length as in the first table (the first table is the reference format). If in the second table I replace `\midrule` by `\noalign{\noindent\rule{\dimexpr15cm+\tabcolsep\relax}{0.5pt}}` as suggested in @Christian Hupfer's answer (note that `\llen` + `\rlen` = 15cm) it almost works but still the length of the lines is not completely equal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newlength{\llen}
\newlength{\rlen}
\setlength{\llen}{5.5cm}
\setlength{\rlen}{9.5cm}

\parindent=0cm

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX &\\\midrule\addlinespace[1ex]
\begin{minipage}[t]{\llen}
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\
\end{minipage}&
\begin{minipage}[t]{\rlen}
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.2cm}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&\\\midrule\addlinespace[1ex]
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The rule lengths look equal to me? What do you want to change? Are you looking for a rule that only spans for a cell? `\cmidrule`? perhaps

Comment: Yes, now both are equal. I want to specify the length of the rule precisely ... 7.75 cm, say. It is not about whether it spans a cell.

Comment: `\noalign{\rule{7.75cm}{1pt}}` for example, but this will shift the rule to the right.

Comment: I don't want to shift it. It should be as it is (starting on the left side) just I want to specify the length precisely in cm.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\noindent`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: sorry, I don't understand, where exactly in my code do I have to put `\noalign{\rule{7.75cm}{1pt}}` ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at the answers. In a hurry, that's why.

Comment: @lpdbw: It would be nice if wouldn't change/edit the change the question requesting some more features after you've already accepted an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is that what you want? I played with the `(lr)` argument for `\cmidrule`, and required a (negative, here) trim on the right, calculated from the column width, which is known thanks to the minipage. If not known, we would have to use the `eqparbox` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
  XXXXXXX & \\\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](r{\dimexpr5.5cm+\tabcolsep-7.75cm\relax}){1-1}\addlinespace[1ex]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{5.5cm}
  AAAAAAAAAAAAA
  \end{minipage}
          &
  \begin{minipage}[t]{9.5cm}
  BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
  \end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
  YYYYYYYYYYYYY & \\\midrule\addlinespace[1ex]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{5.5cm}
  CCCCCCCCC
  \end{minipage}
                &
  \begin{minipage}[t]{9.5cm}
  DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
  \end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a solution to the second problem: to shorten typing I define a `\fakemidrule` command which does what you want. Your error in the code you tried is you forgot the space between wo columns is equal to `2` \tabcolsep.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newlength{\llen}
\newlength{\rlen}
\setlength{\llen}{5.5cm}
\setlength{\rlen}{9.5cm}
\newcommand\fakemidrule{\noalign{\vskip\aboverulesep\noindent\rule{\dimexpr\llen + \rlen+2\tabcolsep\relax}{\lightrulewidth}}}
\parindent=0cm

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & \\
  \midrule\addlinespace[1ex]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\llen}
  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\
  \end{minipage} &
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\rlen}
  YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
  \end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.2cm}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & \\
  \fakemidrule
  \addlinespace[1ex]
  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Excellent idea, the same came into my mind! Advantage: same `\arrayrulewidth`.

Comment: @Bernard does your edit address the edit of my post? I don't understand.

Comment: @lpdbw: Not at all. I just fount there were  some (minor) typos in *my* post and I corrected them.

Comment: I see, so do you have any solution to my edit? I would appreciate a lot!!

Comment: @lpdbw: I do have a solution. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

A rule with an arbitrary length can be specified with `\rule{length}{width}`, however, this would be placed in the table cell.

To spread over the cells, use `\noalign{\noindent\rule{7.75cm}{2pt}}` (change the dimensions at will) (Thanks to @touhami for the hint with `\noindent`)

`\noalign` prevents the aligning in cells, all content is then basically set as if no table cells were present, leaving the usual `\parindent` indentation. To get rid off this, `\noindent` can be used (or `\parindent` set to zero)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}

XXXXXXX&\\
\noalign{\noindent\rule{7.75cm}{2pt}}\addlinespace[1ex]
\midrule\addlinespace[1ex]
\begin{minipage}[t]{5.5cm}
AAAAAAAAAAAAA
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}[t]{9.5cm}
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
YYYYYYYYYYYYY&\\\midrule\addlinespace[1ex]
\begin{minipage}[t]{5.5cm}
CCCCCCCCC
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}[t]{9.5cm}
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the first line should be `XXXXXXX&\\ \noalign{\noindent\rule{7.75cm}{.5pt}}\addlinespace[1ex]`

Comment: @AboAmmar: Yes, right, I added the `\addlinespace` command. Thanks. The rest is to the O.P. ;-)

Comment: I have marked the previous answer as the accepted one. But actually I am not sure which of both answers is more elegant. If people who are more knowledgeable than me in LaTeX share their opinion which one is better I will be glad to change. I think for the database it is important to mark the answers as accepted which is objectively better. So please let me know.

Comment: @lpdbw: Bernard's answer is good and I can't say that mine is better. My answer is a little bit shorter, however. It's your decision. I upvoted his answer of course.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Could you maybe have a look at the EDIT in my original post? I am working towards a deadline today and haven't found a solution yet. Thx so much.

Comment: @lpdbw: Deadlines are always bad.

Comment: @lpdbw: Use `\noalign{\noindent\rule{15cm+2\tabcolsep}{2pt}}` then. You need `\usepackage{calc}` to get the calculation correct. The inner `ll` columns have a `\tabcolsep` space to the right and the left, you canceled the outer ones already with `@{}`. `\tabcolsep` defaults to `6pt`, usually

Comment: Yep, great, this seems to work! Yeah, deadlines are bad :-)